# Loading csv file in chunks

Tags: python, pandas

I have [data set](https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2018-01.csv) of 2.5 GB which contain tens of millions of rows

I'm trying to load data like

```
 %%time
 import pandas as pd
 data=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\mahes_000\\Desktop\\yellow.csv',iterator=True,
                  chunksize=50000)
```

Where I'm getting multiple of chunksize part and I'm trying to do some operations like

```
 %%time
 data.get_chunk().head(5)
 data.get_chunk().shape
 data.get_chunk().drop(['Rate_Code'],axis=1)
```

For operation it choose any one chunksize part and do all the operation it.
Then what about the remaining parts?
How can I do operations on complete data without memory-error.

Comment: You need to loop through the iterator. `for i in data` and perform the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on the parameter [`chunksize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> Return TextFileReader object for iteration

Thus by placing the object in a loop you will iteratively read the data in chunks specified in `chunksize`:

```
chunksize = 5e4
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    #print(chunk.head(5))
    #print(chunk.shape())
```

Comment: Can you add some process on chunk so that i will get reference.

Comment: Well @Mahesh, `chunk` is a dataframe, so you can perform any process you have in mind directly on it.